# My connection to a Mysql DB has been blocked after spamming queries, for how long?

Tags: mysql, access-control, blocking

I am creating a web application that depends on querying a legacy DB without an API.

It's MySql.

Off course the lack of an API eventually got me in trouble. A feedback loop while testing the app fired a bunch of (Probably a few hundred) get requests towards the database, and now i can't connect to it anymore, it simply times out.

I horrified tried to log into to it via the browser and PHPmyAdmin, and to my relief nothing was wrong, but in Status->Processes i can see this process:

```
Kill    25289014    myusername  localhost   None    Query   0   ---
```

I reckon the DB killed all incoming connections from my user when i began to spam it from my application.

Do any of you guys know if the "block" will be lifted after a certain amount of hours. It's about 12 hours ago now.

Or if i have to contact the administrator to lift the block, or kill the kill process? My user doesn't seem to have the privilege to kill the process as there is no buttons to do so.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Query spamming? First I've heard of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

If you have the [**RELOAD privilege**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload), you can run this

```
mysql> FLUSH HOSTS;
```

According to MySQL Documentation on running [**FLUSH HOSTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html):

> Empties the host cache. You should flush the host cache if some of your hosts change IP address or if the error message Host 'host_name' is blocked occurs. (See Section B.5.2.6, “Host 'host_name' is blocked”.) When more than max_connect_errors errors occur successively for a given host while connecting to the MySQL server, MySQL assumes that something is wrong and blocks the host from further connection requests. Flushing the host cache enables further connection attempts from the host. The default value of max_connect_errors is 10. To avoid this error message, start the server with max_connect_errors set to a large value.

You should run this command

```
SELECT host,Reload_priv FROM mysql.user
WHERE user = 'mysqluser';
```

If nothing appears, then you do not have the [**RELOAD privilege**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload). Consequently, you have no choice but to contact the system administrators to run `FLUSH HOSTS;` for you.

## ALTERNATIVE SUGGESTION

Ask the system administrators to configure [**max_connect_errors**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors) in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
max_connect_errors = 18446744073709551615;
```

To avoid restarting mysql, ask the system administrators to run this

```
mysql> set global max_connect_errors = 18446744073709551615;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**